# Execute Conditional HTTP Request using Backconnect or Rotating Proxies

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, ip

There are many sites (such as microleaves.com) that allow you to change your external IP address by connecting to a master proxy. You connect to a master proxy and the master proxy routes your IP to an external proxy. The external IP can change at any time (for example, if one of the external proxies stop working it is automatically replaced by a different proxy by the master proxy/IP).

I'm using this type of service to navigate to different websites via the Selenium framework - is it possible to prevent a request from executing if the external proxy changes?

For example, suppose at the present moment my external IP is 1.1.1.1.1 and suddenly the IP changes to 2.2.2.2.2 - is there a way to programmatically instruct program to execute request or navigate to a site only if my external IP is still equal to 1.1.1.1.1?

The purpose of this is that I would like to retrieve certain characteristics of the new proxy (such as the city, state or ISP) before actually executing a request with the proxy.

Someone might suggest simply making a request to an external server to get my external IP before executing each request - however it is possible that the external IP will change immediately after I do this - how can I guarantee consistency of external IP?

Comment: I think you should address this question to proxy provider - may be they have some API to get info about current proxy state

Comment: @IvanPronin I don't think the API supports this functionality - this is precisely why I want to know if it can be achieved on my end.